# Core Bluetooth: Unknown CBService?

Tags: cocoa, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

To learn CB, I've decided to browse the services on my iPhone. I'm finding a few, but except Battery and Time, the others are "Unknown". What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Some services have defined UUIDs (such a battery and time) and these are listed on the [Bluetooth Developer Portal](https://developer.bluetooth.org/gatt/services/Pages/ServicesHome.aspx).  The defined services also have a set of defined characteristic IDs

BLE also allows developers to specify their own service and characteristic UUIDs - since the chance of collision for random UUIDs is infinitesimal, there is no requirement to register these, but organisations may choose to document them.  [Apple's notification center service](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW8) defines some, for example, and many chipset/module vendors define services to make it simpler for developers to use their modules.

Looking at my Fitbit Flex I can see device information and battery services - these are well known, as well as two unknown services which, presumably, FitBit use to transfer activity and configuration information to and from the device.  Short of trying to reverse-engineer their protocol there is no other information available on these services and characteristics.